# Music playlist creator with export capabilities

Tags: streaming, music-production, radio

I need to be able to use my own MP3 files and create playlists.

I am using a music scheduling software at the moment (meant for radio channels). It's too expensive and I don't produce any live content. So I don't need most of the features.

I just need to create a playlist and export a file I can use for streaming. Are there any good playlist creators with categories tags and rules?

Comment: For which operating system?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are looking for exactly, but most modern music players can create playlists in m3u format or others.

[MusicBee](http://getmusicbee.com/) can create both static playlists or so called "Smart Playlists" which are built automatically from your music library or a subset of it, using any of a multitude of filters and rules.

Besides those it can have regular playlists built from manually added files.

All of them can be configured for automatic export to static m3U files upon exit, effectively maintaining up to date files ready for use in other players, or devices.

Export options include a customizable folder, Windows or Unix file path convention, relative paths, and more.